# Apache connection intermittantly times out on LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, timeout

I'm using Fedora 12 with Apache 2.2.14, and I was having this error on 2.2.13 as well.

Even when I connect to my server over LAN, Firefox will occasionally time out while connecting. I can't figure out what is causing this. The error log isn't showing anything. I even cleaned the error log file, so that if something happened, it'd be a little easier to spot. But I'm still getting time outs, and nothing in the error log.

Can anybody help me find what the problem is?

Here is my httpd.conf
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f2e78d861)

It's the default Fedora configuration; I've only changed the ServerName if I remember correctly.
I'm pretty sure it's not the Timeout setting, because on LAN it should never time out.
I don't believe it's a load issue either, I'm the only one connecting to it.

I'm not an Apache expert, so if more information is needed I'll need some instructions on how to get that data.

Comment: `tcpdump` output or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

are you connecting via ip address or hostname? if hostname, try it by IP or add a static entry to /etc/hosts.